# Ver Inserts fallidos SQLSERVER

Tags: sql-server, sql, transact-sql

Estoy realizando una integración, donde la aplicación ejecuta varias querys automáticamente. En este caso intenta realizar un insert, y si no lo consigue repite cada dos minutos la operación.

No se están realizando porque lo intenta con datos erróneos, el problema reside en que no tengo acceso al código fuente de esta aplicación y no puedo hacerle un debug para ver como realiza dicha consulta.

Alguna forma de consultar los insert y demás consultas erróneas que se intentaron contra una base de datos? Tengo permisos de administrador en esa BD.

Alguna query como las de ver las transacciones pero para ver un histórico de consultas ejecutadas?

Comment: No tienes acceso al codigo? Haz un insert de prueba, y luego haz una select de prueba para los datos que has metido en los insert. Deberias saber si hace un rollback si es fallido, si no lo hace, es posible que te meta los datos correctos y no los incorrectos, entonces haz una select por cada campo y podras ver los que ha metido.

Comment: @cupax64 no hace rollback, intenta el insert y en caso de fallar, sigue hacia delante. Entonces detecto el error, porque intenta acceder a la nueva fila a través de una clave foránea, pero esa clave primaria que debiera estar insertada no existe. Si hago un insert manual no tengo problema, pero necesito ver que datos envía la aplicación para saber por qué falla.

Comment: Los datos, los sacas de un formulario? Si es asi, create un archivo php, y pasate los datos del formulario al php y comprueba que contienen.

Comment: @cupax64 lamentablemente no sale de un formulario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crea una trigger para las inserciones de tipo **INSTEAD OF** en tu tabla. En este trigger incluirás que antes de insertar en tu tabla original (dbo.TuTabla) inserte en otra tabla adicional (en el ejemplo dbo.TABLA2).

`CREATE TRIGGER [dbo.] tr_inserciones
ON dbo.TuTabla
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN 
  insert into dbo.TABLA2 (campo1,campo2,campo3)
  select campo1, campo2, campo3 from inserted

  insert into dbo.TuTabla (campo1,campo2,campo3)
  select campo1, campo2, campo3 from inserted

END`

Answer (score 2):

Y si lo intentas con SQLProfiler? Es una herramienta que tiene el ssms..
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez creada la traza podrás capturas todas las querys que se ejecutan, te recomiendo que pongas filtros 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Una forma alternativa de ver todo lo que pasa en tu base de datos, es usar los Eventos Extendidos. Son una herramienta que funciona como la evolución de SQL Profiler y tiene más características, mejores funcionalidades y menor impacto en el rendimiento de la instancia.

La documentación de SQL Server tiene extensivas explicaciones de como hacerlo, así como lo han hecho en múltiples blogs.

[Inicio rápido: Eventos extendidos en SQL Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/quick-start-extended-events-in-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)